# ReactJs: How to build npm library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I am new to react. I want to build a npm reactjs library. I have a reactjs project and I want to general it as a package(library) that can be used by other project. For example, people can use "npm install" command to import my project.

Comment: This might help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-own-npm-package-and-publish-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit package name in package.json
2. Publish a package

   npm publish --access public

   [ref](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages#creating-a-scoped-public-package)

Comment: Got it. By the way, do I need to sign up npm account?

Comment: @reactnative Right  you must have npm account . after register use npm login